# How to alter proxy objects in Vuex / Vue3

Tags: vuex, vuejs3

I'm trying to update the vuex store but it looks like vuex/vue 3 has converted the state to Proxy objects. How to insert new item in Proxy Objects?

i was trying to add item like normal objects like this

```
  addUnitToCurrentOwner(state, unit) {
    const { data } = unit.response;
    const newOwnedUnit = [data,
      ...state.currentOwner.owned_units];
    state.currentOwner.owned_units = newOwnedUnit;
  },
```

but it looks like the existing objects are in Proxy?
[screenshot of console log here ->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEHVD.png)

how to I add new item/s to proxy objects?

Answer (score 0):

This is not how Vue works. The thing that makes Vue reactive, are Proxies. That's why all the objects are wrapped in Proxies. If you want to change a value in the vuex store then please follow the official [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html), and use `Mutations`.